# linux - cannot view directory created from java

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-applications

I am using the following piece of code to create a directory in java, under Linux:

```
String dir = "~/tempDir/";
if (!IOUtils.createDirectory(dir)) {
    throw new IOException("could no create the local store directory: "
            + dir );
}

LOGGER.info("local store successfully created.");
```

The application seems to create the directory, as I get no errors and it is working fine.
The problem is that I cannot see this directory on the disk; I am looking in my home directory.
I need to mention that this is a java web application running under tomcat.

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot see this directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not work because `~` is expanded by your shell, `bash` or `sh` or whatever. This doesn't work from Java.

You have created a directory called `~` in your working directory.

You need to get the user's home directory from the system property `user.home` and build your path from that.

```
final File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "tempDir");
```

Comment: and do you have any idea where this directory is created if I am running the application under tomcat? I can't find it in the location where the class that creates it is.

Comment: You could `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())`, this will give you the working directory. Where tomcat's working directory is depends on how you start tomcat.

Comment: Addon : Check the value of user.home system property first :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a "New Folder" under Home, if a folder with the specified name does NOT exist already

```
final String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/";
final String folderName = "New Folder";

File file = new File(homePath + folderName);

if (!file.exists())
    file.mkdir();
```

Another option (a better one I should say) you have is using another constructor of File that takes a parent path and a child path as follows:

```
final String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
final String folderName = "New Folder";

File file = new File(homePath, folderName);

if (!file.exists())
    file.mkdir();
```

Comment: Hm. Always you the _other_ constructor for `File`; use `new File(File parent, File child)` and similar. Avoid, at all costs, hard-coding path separators and concatenating paths from strings. This solution is very error-prone and, quite frankly, not good.

Comment: If it were a project I was doing for myself, I would probably use
>new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "New Folder").mkdir();
But it seemed like half the question was about figuring out how to tell Java to create a folder in "Home." So, I thought my snipped would be easier to read than the way you suggested.

Comment: Well add that to your answer in that case. The issue with your answer is that it gives bad advice.